# I need a unique subset of data from my table using SQL

Tags: sql, unique, dbase

I am working with a Dbase table via SQL commands. I have the following free table to work with.

### import1

account, phone, subaccount, locationid

I need the first occurrence of each uinique combination of account and phone. No one field in the table is unique. I can get a partial subset of data using the distinct qualifier but i need the other fields that relate to the record its selecting also.

Can this be done?
Thanks

Edit: I found out that I need to qualify the selected records must stay intact.

Example:

### Import1

001    123-4567    123    0110

001    123-0001    234    0220

001    123-4567    456    0011

002    222-2222    010    0110

003    333-3333    333    0330

should return

### import1

001    123-4567    123    0110

001    123-0001    234    0220

002    222-2222    010    0110

003    333-3333    333    0330

That's my intent here.

Comment: What is the primary key of the table? You said that no one column is unique; what combination of columns is unique?

Comment: Its an imported CSV. It doesn't contain a key. The subset i wish to end up with is each row of data for witch the combination account + phone is unique.

Comment: Hey guys, any reason why this wouldn't work? select account, min(phone), min(subaccount), min(locationid) from import1 group by account, phone it seems to return what I am looking for so far. Am I missing anything?

Comment: That should work @Donovan, as does my query below.

Comment: Yeah that should work fine Donovan.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration. :)

Comment: @Donovan, do you really mean Ashton Tate's DBase: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbase , or are you just using "dbase" as an abbreviation of "database"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, no matter how you slice it, you need a unique key. It can be a combination of columns, but you absolutely must have some means of uniquely identifying each row. Without that, your best recourse is to add such a constraint. In addition to that constraint, this type of request is best served by also having a single unique column. However, if you do not have such a column, you can create it from the columns that do comprise the unique key by concatenating them together:

```
Select T1.account, T1.phone, T1.subaccount, T1.locationId....
From "Table" As T1
Where (Cast(T1.UniqueCol1 As varchar(100)) 
    + "|" + Cast(T2.UniqueCol2 As varchar(100)
    ... ) = (
            Select Min( Cast(T2.UniqueCol1 As varchar(100))
                        + "|" + Cast(T2.UniqueCol2 As varchar(100))
                        ... 
                        ) 
            From "Table" As T2
            Where T2.account = T1.account
                And T2.phone = T1.phone
            )
```

In this case `UniqueCol1` represents one of the columns of the unique key, `UniqueCol2` represents the next and so on. This will not be a fast query by any means. Having a single column guaranteed to be unique would make this problem significantly simpler. With that, you can do something akin to Mike M's solution:

```
Select T1.account, T1.phone, T1.subaccount, T1.locationId....
From "Table" As T1
Where UniqueCol = (
                    Select Min( T2.UniqueCol ) 
                    From "Table" As T2
                    Where T2.account = T1.account
                        And T2.phone = T1.phone
                    )
```

An important point to be made here is that in both solutions above "first" is being determined simply by the lowest sorted key value found. If "first" needs to be determined by something else, like a datetime column, you need to mention that your in your post.

**EDIT**

Given your addition that this is an import, the simplest solution is to add an auto-incrementing column to your staging table. In SQL Server this would be an IDENTITY column but other database products have an equivalent. If you do that, then the last solution I presented above will do the trick (simply replace UniqueCol with the name of your Identity column).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By account) AS Id
INTO #Table FROM import1
```

Now you've got a primary key-

```
    SELECT account, phone, MAX(Id) AS Id
    FROM #Table
    GROUP BY account, phone
```

EDIT: I forgot the important part. doh.

```
SELECT * FROM #Table T
WHERE T.Id IN (
        SELECT MAX(Id) AS Id
        FROM #Table
        GROUP BY account, phone )
```

Comment: I'm working in Visual Fox Pro and the Row_Number() function isn't available to me. Your solution did lead me to the comment i posted below though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a unique collection of Phone/Account info and THEN you want to get each Sub Account and Location for that unique combo.  Is this correct?

If i'm understanding you correctly you may want to make new tables or views in the following format:

```
import1
-------
id  |Phone  | Account

SubAccount  //SubAccountId may not be needed here...
----------
SubAccountId  |ImportId  | SubAccount

ImportLocation
--------------
ImportId |LocationId
```

Let me know if I missunderstood what you are trying to do...

**UPDATE:**

This modified version of your suggestion should work. Only took the Min off of Phone and added a distinct:

```
Select distinct account, 
       phone, 
       min(subaccount), 
       min(locationid) 
from  import1 
group by account, phone
```

Comment: Hey guys, any reason why this wouldn't work?  

  select account, min(phone), min(subaccount), min(locationid) from import1 group by account, phone  
  
it seems to return what I am looking for so far. Am I missing anything?

Comment: That's not entirely true. The subaccount and location ids are trivial. Whatever unique records are selected based on account + phone it just has to carry the subaccount and location data associated with it into the new table.

Comment: Yeah if you can arbitrarily select 1 of many phone, subaccount and locationId then the method you described should work.  I was thinking you needed to maintain the relationships between these and their corresponding Account.

Comment: so your not destroying the relationship then? What if you have two account + phone records with varying subaccount and location id data. Will the data related to the record distinct has selected be returned for sure?

Comment: It seems to me that by taking the min values you are destroying any relationships between the data anyways.  You are basically forcing a one to many relationship into a one to one relationship.  It's possible that I'm still misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve though.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more elegant solution:

```
SELECT account, phone, subaccount, locationid
FROM import1
WHERE account IN
(SELECT DISTINCT account, phone FROM import1)
```

Comment: it may be my IDE but I cant use the IN clause when the left side of the where statement doesn't contain the same fields at the right side, in this case the sub query.

Comment: Then the more complex queries it is!

Answer (score 0):

```
select account, min(phone), min(subaccount), min(locationid) 
from import1 
group by account, phone
```

Seems the best solution for my IDE ( Visual Fox Pro v9 )

Comment: Mike M has pointed out in a different thread that this solution destroys the integrity of the records having the unique value account + phone. It includes the minimum values for locationid and subaccount not the associated values with the record having account+phone. crud.